# Getting specific datetime format in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datetime-format

I need to get a specific time format in C# like this:

```
2016-010-31T00:00:00:000Z
```

I tried:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

But this does not produces what I want...

How can I get the current datetime in this exact format like above??

Comment: Well have you looked at the documentation for [custom date and time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I have but I couldnt find the one I was looking for... I probably missed it out somewhere in bunch of those formats

Comment: The idea is that you create the format you want out of the specifiers available... I suggest you read it again, more thoroughly.

Comment: See this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Roundtrip

Comment: gotta say - a 3-digit month seems kind of weird

Comment: Yeah thats what I've thgouth as well... I'm passing this to PayPal API and whichever format I've tried I get errors ... :/

Comment: @User987 Just use DateTime class in your classes  and serialize your object using Json.Net. You'll get a standard date format....

Comment: If the 3 character date is just a typo, that looks like the standard serialized format for DateTimes.

Comment: Pretty sure you are looking for the [round trip DateTime format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Roundtrip).  So, `DateTime.Now.ToString("O");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
string output = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-0MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffZ");
```

I'm not sure about the "Z", if you wanted some time zone info. I zero padded the month like your example. Obviously there would never be a needed third decimal place.

Comment: I'm new. Is there something wrong with this answer that I'm getting down votes?